# How can I address map elements in JexlExpression?

Tags: java, expression, jexl

I have a function that is suppose to evaluate some expressions in the loop using JexlEngine. It receive as a parameter List<Map<String,Object>> and run through that list.
Can I place the whole map to JexlContext and use in my JexlExpression parameters like map.key, similarly to object.property, or I have to manually put every Map element into context? I am at the beginning of writing the code, thus can't post it here, but in JEXL documentation didn't find anything on the topic. If I missed it, please drop me a link.

Comment: No problem, you can create one context per (some) map with: `new MapContext(someMap)` [javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/apidocs/org/apache/commons/jexl3/MapContext.html), [example](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/examples.html) ..but also a good question: At all/How will you aggregate the list?

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the wrong example. I do not need to aggregate the list. I am getting my data from the database using Spring JdbcTemplate https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList(java.lang.String)